# Was Sphinx renamed Sphinx-doc, or is it still just Sphinx?

Tags: namespaces, python-sphinx

The  Release-monitoring URL refers to it as sphinx-doc - https://release-monitoring.org/project/11124/

And the Home Page has been http://sphinx-doc.org/ since at least 2012-11-04 when Georg Brandl made git change [4763419db1f964a2aa1dbf9ce214fde12710b08e](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/commit/4763419db1f964a2aa1dbf9ce214fde12710b08e).

But on the other hand [Sphinx-doc](https://github.com/sphinx-doc) appears as an enclosure for other related sub-components within GIT.

I had thought that I had seen discussion on the name change where it was renamed from Sphinx to Sphinx-doc to clarify the difference between the other similarly named tools; see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_(documentation_generator)).

Adding a tag to this question I find the tag with the correct description is python-sphinx.

You may be asking [what's in a name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What%27s_in_a_Name%3F)?  I'm just wanting to refer to correct name :-)

Comment: As long as you run `pip install sphinx`, you know what's the correct name. `sphinx-doc` can be simply "Documentation of Sphinx".

Comment: But `brew install sphinx` will get you Sphinx search!

Comment: It depends on the context. Do you want the package name, website name, SO tag, other? Let's just say that branding is not a strength of open source software. ;)